# Declare object with 'using' statement for later purposes

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

Can we use the `using` statement in a constructor to declare an instance of an object for later usage. For example.

```
public class TestClass {

   private DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

   public TestClass(string connString){
       using (this._dataContext =  DataClassesDataContext(connString));
    }

   private bool someMethod(){
       _dataContext.instanceMethod(); // i want to use instance methods wherever needed and define once
   }
}
```

Comment: very interesting question, would bet that `_dataContext` will be disposed at the end of initialization though

Comment: What do you expect to gain by being able to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must implement `IDisposable` yourself and call `Dispose` on the data context from you `Dispose` method.

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable {

   private DataClassesDataContext _dataContext;

   public TestClass(string connString){
       _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(connString);
    }

   private bool someMethod(){
       _dataContext.instanceMethod(); // i want to use instance methods wherever needed and define once
   }

   public void Dispose(){
       _dataContext.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: I had to make my class 'sealed' for this to work. Still don't understand why but thanks.

Comment: @Warz If your class is not sealed you need to make dispose virtual in case derived classes also need to make members disposed. See [the MSDN page on Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) for the way to create the pattern.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what you expect the `using` statement to *do* here. All it does is make sure that `Dispose` is called at the end of the block.

So basically you'd be creating a `DataClassesDataContext` (I assume you missed the `new` keyword...), storing a reference in a field, and then immediately disposing of it. That's not going to work well - you should get rid of the `using` statement, but quite possibly make your class implement `IDisposable` so that when the instance of `TestClass` is disposed, you dispose of the data context.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

> The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the
>   correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the
>   object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.

The using statement is basically syntactic sugar for try/finally.

```
 try
  {
    _dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(connString);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (_dataContext != null)
      ((IDisposable)dataContext).Dispose();
  }
```

Looking at it in this way it should become obvious that datacontext is no longer in scope and therefore can't be used by other methods as you desire.  To solve the problem, you should make the class implement `IDisposeable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (this._dataContext =  DataClassesDataContext(connString));
```

is the same as

```
try
{
    this._dataContext =  DataClassesDataContext(connString);
}
catch
{

}
finally
{
    if(this._dataContext!=null)
             ((IDisposable)this._dataContext).Dispose();
}
```

So you'll get _dataContext disposed in you constructor and it will be no longer available. You should implement `IDisposable` interface and you'll be able to employ `using` statement where you want like this:

```
using (TestClass test = new TestClass("conn"))
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: and now explain that to your OP and not to someone who knows what you do there